Sign Safe transaction with an Alchemy Light account owner
There's a multi-owner gnosis safe who's owners are:

Another gnosis safe
Alchemy light account

Below code works perfectly when I sign a transaction with a Safe.
But it crashes when I try to sign it with a Light Account.
Any idea how to make it work?
const signer = await browserProvider.getSigner();
const safeSdk = await Safe.init({
      provider: this.provider,
      signer: signer.address,
      safeAddress: executorSafe,
    });
const transaction = await safeSdk.createTransaction({...});
const conn = await safeSdk.connect({ safeAddress: signingAccount });
const signedTx = await conn.signTransaction(
      transaction,
      SigningMethod.SAFE_SIGNATURE,
      executorSafe,
    );

The error I'm getting:
Error: missing revert data (action="call", data=null, reason=null, transaction={ "data": "0xffa1ad74", "from": "0x57...182", "to": "0x0B1b...bb8" },


Have you tried passing signingAccount as the signer instead of the safeAddress in await safeSdk.connect()?
Since a Light Account is not a Safe, what you tried would be expected to fail. (I am assuming signingAccount is the Light Account, is this correct?).
Please let me know  Best, Louis

Thanks for your reply! Do you mean like this?
const conn = await safeSdk.connect({ signer: signingSafe });
I tried it, but this line gives an error:
SafeTransactionSender.ts:246
POST https://sepolia.base.org/ 403 (Forbidden)
Error: could not coalesce error (error={ "code": -32603, "data": { "cause": null, "error": { "code": -32601, "message": "rpc method is unsupported" }, "id": "m2v5revvzm", "jsonrpc": "2.0" }, "payload": { "method": "eth_requestAccounts", "params": [  ] } }, payload={ "method": "eth_requestAccounts", "params": [  ] },

I followed up here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/165283/safe-sdk-1-4-1-singing-safe-transaction-with-a-light-account-owner
