Safe SDK 1.4.1 - singing safe transaction with a light account owner
Our project has a requirement to sign Safe transactions with an Alchemy light account that owns a safe. This is the code I came up with:
const alchemyClient = await createLightAccountAlchemyClient({...});
const typedData: TypedDataDefinition = {
        domain: {...},
        types: {...},          
        primaryType: "SafeTx",
        message: {...},
      }
const alchemySig = await alchemyClient.signTypedData({typedData});
const signature = new EthSafeSignature(signingAccount, alchemySig);
const signedTx = await safeSdk.copyTransaction(transaction)
signedTx.addSignature(signature);

The signing is working, however the transaction doesn't go through: https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/base-sepolia/0x88630a14fff07e4cea305cd0911b053a5fb662fe9525143850034111803b5871
I've contacted the Alchemy team and they say it's because the Safe account is using
isValidSignature(bytes memory _data, bytes memory _signature)

instead of
isValidSignature(bytes32 _hash, bytes memory _signature)

I saw that the main branch has a fix for that
https://github.com/safe-global/safe-smart-account/blob/main/contracts/Safe.sol#L255
My question is when will it be released? We have to make a decision whether we want to launch with Safe accounts or look for alternatives.

You have two options:

Use approveTransactionHash to pre-approve a safe transaction hash;
Deploy an adapter contract that becomes the actual Safe owner and delegates signature validation to the light client. Essentially, an adapter between the legacy and current EIP-1271.


I can't use approveTransactionHash because I can't initialize the SDK with the light account as a signer. If I could do that, I would have just used protocolKit.signTransaction().

You can then use the second option: create an intermediary contract (an adapter) between the two implementations of EIP-1271, and use it until a new version is released. The team is working hard on the next release, which will include these changes, but there isn't any precise timeline yet. Please hang tight in the mean time, and feel free to open new questions if you are having any trouble implementing the adapter contract

Thanks Louis, we will try to deploy an adapter.
